# mysql - return table from a stored proc in another stored proc

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have storedproc1, in this I want to calls usp_splitDelimitedStr. usp_splitDelimitedStr creates a temp table and selects from it
I want to use the values returned from usp_splitDelimitedStr to insert them in a column in temp table created in storedproc1.
So it looks like this,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE storedproc1
 (
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmpAdditionalInfo 
    (FieldKeys VARCHAR(255), FieldValues VARCHAR(255));

.....

-- here I insert into the column using the 
INSERT INTO tmpAdditionalInfo(FieldKeys) VALUES (CALL usp_splitDelimitedStr(In_OrderFieldKeys,'|'));

)
```

Note: The background to this is am using the usp_splitDelimitedStr to split a delimited string and return the splitted strings (to the caller i.e. storedproc1) by selecting them from a temp table it has created, I can't use a function because its not possible to return table in function in mysql.

Any advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the procedure, and then `SELECT` from the temporary table that it created in the `INSERT` statement:

```
CALL usp_splitDelimitedStr(In_OrderFieldKeys, '|');

INSERT INTO tmpAdditionalInfo (FieldKeys)
SELECT FieldKeys
FROM tableCreatedBy_usp_splitDelimitedStr;
```

Comment: thanks, how safe is this approach in a scenario where i have multiple connnections executing my storedproc1? (this db will be serving a website)

Comment: Temporary tables are private to each connection.

Comment: thanks, I have decided againsst taking this approach i.e sending delimited string to the database and splitting it in my stored proc. Instead I will use php to do a direct insert of the would be delimited strings